# How to get rid of annoying InnoSetup folder selection mechanism?

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup

When I set:

DefaultDirName={pf}\My program

in InnoSetup .iss file, it starts directory selection with this path correctly. However, if user press 'Browse' button and start navigating through filesystem, InnoSetup keeps 'My program' suffix at the end of path chosen by user. How to get rid of this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found it myself :) The answer is to set AppendDefaultDirName to no.